# jQuery datepicker opens with the wrong date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm having a problem with the jQuery datepicker in that it does not want to open with the correct date if I use a date format other than yy-m-d.  The reason I don't want to use this format is because I want an easy to read format because it's basically the title of this page so it should look nice (it's for a staff timesheet).

Here's how I initialize my datepicker: (notice I'm using altField and altFormat)

```
$('#formattedpagedate').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  dateFormat: 'DD, d M, yy',
  altField: '#pagedate',
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showAnim: 'slideDown',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  showButtonPanel: false,
  autoClose: true,
  showOn: 'both',
  buttonImage: 'images/icons/stock/calendar.png',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  defaultDate: '".$pagedate."',
  buttonText: 'Select a different date',
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    timesheetRefresh();
  }
});
```

Here's my HTML (simplified for the purposes of this post)

```
<input type=text id=pagedate name=pagedate value='".$pagedate."' readonly style='border:none;width:0px'>
<input type=text id=formattedpagedate class=clickable readonly value='".$formattedpagedate."'>
```

Obviously I'm using PHP to populate the values of these inputs as well as the default date on initialization of the datepicker.  Basically what I'm doing is hiding the altField (pagedate) with a 0px width, and displaying a user friendly formatted date field (formattedpagedate).  So it's the altField value that I'm sending to the database because it's formatted the way I need, and it's the formatted field that I'm showing to the user and which the user can click on.

The problem is when the user clicks on the formatted date the calendar opens to Oct 3, 2021 (which I'm assuming means it doesn't understand the date).

If I set the date format to anything other than **yy-m-d** or **yy-mm-dd** the calendar opens to the wrong date.  Even just leaving out the hyphens or using periods instead of hyphens breaks the datepicker.

If I set the date format to yy-mm-dd the calendar opens to the correct date and I can still format the displaydate when the page first loads, so that's fine, but if the user chooses a new date I lose the nice format and it looks kinda stupid.

Is it possible to get the datepicker to return a date in my chosen format?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?